Center a matrix in a box?
I have a matrix of integers that I would like to center in a rectangular frame; however, as you can see, there is a little extra space below the matrix. How can I equalize the space above and below? (In my actual document, the matrix is actually meant to fit in a TikZ node; however, \boxed illustrates the issue equally well.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $\boxed{\begin{matrix}
      1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4
  \end{matrix}}$
\end{document}



My suggestion would be to follow the \tikzmark approach listed here: Highlight elements in the matrix, because you're already using TikZ.

Matrix adds a \strut to each row, as shown in the following.  You can remove the excess at the bottom with \vspace{-\dp\strutbox}, but no idea about the excess space at the top.  I would suggest just trying \vspace values until it look good to you.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \fboxsep=0pt
  $\boxed{\begin{matrix}
      1\smash{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}} & 2 \\
      3 & \smash{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1pt}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}4
  \end{matrix}}$
\end{document}


